# Given a list of nodes, how to find the nodes that connect to every node in the list in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a relationship like (Supplier) --[supplies] -- (Product).
Given a list of products, how can I find the supplier that supplies every product in the list?

Comment: What if there are more than one supplier in the result?

Comment: Are you trying to output each product with its respective supplier(s)? Or are you trying to find a common supplier that supplies all of the given products?

Comment: @rpax if there are more than one supplier that supplies every product in the list, we need to find out them all.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I am trying to find a common supplier that supplies all of the given products.

Comment: A good recursive function would do the trick here.

Answer (score 3):

Tore's answer is a great general approach, and should be favored as long as it performs well.

But if there's a huge set of suppliers, this query may run into performance issues, as it must do the WHERE ALL test for every single supplier in your db.

We can compensate for that by finding all the suppliers of one of the products in the list, and use that as the suppliers to evaluate instead of every supplier.

```
WITH listOfProducts, HEAD(listOfProducts) as prod1
MATCH (supplier:Supplier)-[:supplies]->(prod1)
WHERE ALL(product IN list_of_products WHERE (supplier) - [:supplies] - (product) )
RETURN supplier
```

Comment: That is an excellent point. Filtering is always slower than pathfinding, so try to narrow by pathfinding first wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH prods_a, prods_b, HEAD(prods_a) AS prod1
MATCH (supplier1:Supplier) - [:supplies] - (prod1)
WHERE ALL(prod_a IN prods_a WHERE (supplier1) - [:supplies] - (prod_a) )
WITH DISTINCT prods_b, HEAD(prods_b) AS prod2, COLLECT(supplier1) AS supplies_a
MATCH (supplier2:Supplier) - [:supplies] -(prod2)
WHERE ALL(prod_b IN prods_b WHERE (supplier2) - [:supplies] - (prod_b) )
WITH supplies_a, COLLECT(supplier2) AS supplies_b
WITH [x IN supplies_a | {supplier: x, supplies: 'products_a'}] + [y IN supplies_b | {supplier: y, supplies: 'products_b'}] AS result_dicts
UNWIND result_dicts AS result_dict
WITH result_dict.supplier AS supplier, result_dict.supplies AS supplies
RETURN supplier, COLLECT(DISTINCT supplies)
```

Trying to keep two separate lists is much harder, as is aggregating the results in any way that makes sense. However, this follows the same basic match and filter structure as InverseFalcon's optimized query. There are serious shenanigans to combine the two and analyze to find the intersection, though.

P.S. The strict answer is to perform a `UNION` query, but this will require analysis outside of Cypher.

```
WITH listOfProductsA, HEAD(listOfProductsA) as prod1
MATCH (supplier:Supplier)-[:supplies]->(prod1)
WHERE ALL(product IN list_of_products WHERE (supplier) - [:supplies] - (product) )
RETURN supplier, 'supplies_a'
UNION
WITH listOfProductsb, HEAD(listOfProductsb) as prod1
MATCH (supplier:Supplier)-[:supplies]->(prod1)
WHERE ALL(product IN list_of_products WHERE (supplier) - [:supplies] - (product) )
RETURN supplier, 'supplies_b'
```

Inserting match logic at the start and right after the `UNION`, of course. You can also drop the strings if you really only want a list of suppliers that provides at least one and no other context, and `UNION` will automatically deduplicate rows.

Comment: I am sorry, in addition to that. Suppose we have two categories of product. Let's say A and B. Each category has many different kinds of products. how can I find the supplier that supplies A or B? And how to find the supplier that supplies A and B?  The supplier does not need to supply every product in A or B, as long as they supply one of them.

Comment: okay, now see update. This is basically an entirely new question though.